# Bluetooth beacon Manufacturer ID

Tags: bluetooth

I was wondering is there a particular organisation you have to contact with regards to reserving a manufacturer ID for a bluetooth beacon? For instance, if we wanted to start mass producing them, ensuring no one else uses a particular ID?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Why yes there is. You must be member of the Bluetooth SIG. See [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/) for more information and a list of current Manufacturer IDs.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the previous answer regarding Bluetooth SIG and Company ID,

I will add a few things:

- Company IDs are assigned by the Bluetooth SIG. In order to get one, your company must first become a member of the Bluetooth SIG. The entry level membership (adopter level) is free.
- Once you are an adopter member, you can submit a request to get a Company ID (also free).
- The company ID is necessary if you want to use the Manufacturer specific data field in order for example to have custom data in the BLE advertisement frames.
- If you plan an building a 'simple' beacon product following, you might not need a Company ID. For Apple's iBeacon format for example, the frame format should use the Apple's company ID as well as their beacon format (see for example this page explaining the ibeacon format : http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/). I belive the Google Eddystone beacon format also do not require beacon manufacturer to have their own company ID.